# Acceder a una variable de metodo $.ajax

Tags: javascript, python, django

Fuera de $.ajax quiero acceder a la variable var=fila. Con un console.log si me devuelve resultados. Como podría solucionarlo?

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/laboratorio/searchLista/',
    method: 'GET',
    data: {'id':id_doctor},
    success: function(resultado){
        if(resultado[0].lista_precios == 'Lista2'){
           var fila="<tr><td>"+result[0].codigo+"</td <td>"+result[0].descripcion+"</td><td>"+result[0].grupo+"</td <td>"+result[0].precio2+"</td><td>"+result[0].tempo_demora+"</td><td><button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' onclick='eliminarFila(" + result[0].id + ");''> </button></td></tr>";
        }
    }
 });
```

Comment: Podrias usar una variable global.

Comment: Hola, la solución no podría ser declarar la variable fila fuera del $.ajax ? Puede ser global dentro de la función, o global dentro de todo la ejecución.

Comment: Por qué no haces el console.log dentro del AJAX? Así como la función success hay una error , pon el log en ambos así te aseguras

Comment: Hola Roberto, deberías buscar en el sitio. Esta pregunta se ha hecho ya en varias ocasiones (con código diferente pero es la misma idea) y tiene respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te sugiero que lo cambies por $.get, y así puedes usar await.

Saludos!.

```js
 async function getDatos() {

 var result = await $.get('/laboratorio/searchLista/', { 'id': id_doctor });

 var fila="<tr><td>"+result[0].codigo+"</td <td>"+result[0].descripcion+"</td><td>"+result[0].grupo+"</td <td>"+result[0].precio2+"</td><td>"+result[0].tempo_demora+"</td><td><button class='btn btn-danger btn-xs' onclick='eliminarFila(" + result[0].id + ");''> </button></td></tr>";
}
```